# Given $|g(x)|\leq M|x-2|$, prove that g is continuous at $x=2$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

Given $|g(x)|\leq M|x-2|$, prove that g is continuous at $x=2$

I am not sure whether the way I solve it is correct or not.

Given any $\epsilon>0$, take $\delta=\frac{\epsilon-|g(2)|}{M}$

$$|x-2|<\delta \implies|g(x)-g(2)|\leq |g(x)|+|g(2)|\leq M|x-2|+|g(2)|<\epsilon$$

Comment: Looks alright to me.

Comment: What ever happened to $g(2)$?

Comment: Why is $M|x - 2| + g(2) \leq M|x-2|$?

Comment: you need $g(2)= 0.$ but it follows from $|g(x)| < M|x-2|$ applied at $x = 2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly right, though the way $g(2)$ just disappears near the end looks rather suspect. It would be safer to start by proving explicitly that $g(2)=0$ so you can discard it early on.

Comment: I changed some part of my work. Is it look correct now?

Comment: x @Alan: How you you know $\frac{\varepsilon-|g(2)|}M$ is positive?

Comment: Since $|g(2)|\leq M|2-2|=0$ and in nature $|g(2)|\geq 0$ can I say that $g(2)=0$?

Comment: x @Alan, it is right that $g(2)=0$, but $|g(2)|>0$ must be a typo ...